# Let's take a moment to congratulate some exceptional users

Tags: discussion, users

First off let me say that I am aware that this post is quite late coming but we can all blame our resident moderator [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor) for that; he has taken longer to get to 100k than I thought. Anyway back to the post...

A few of our users "recently" hit some very impressive milestones and I think a post is in order to highlight their amazing achievements.

## [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum)

Valorum hit a very impressive 400k on 29/01/2019!

## [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14111/user14111)

user14111 hit an impressive 100k on 24/01/2019!

## [Bellatrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/80602/bellatrix)

Bellatrix hit an impressive 75k on 25/02/2019!

I, for one, want to take a moment to congratulate these three very impressive users of our site and the amazing contributions they have put forth during their time here.

#### Thank you!

Comment: And I’m proud of having 2K...

Comment: And I'm proud of having anything at all.

Comment: @stormblessed - We all started somewhere. When I joined, they told me DVK and Thaddeus were 'uncatchable'

Comment: Just another 2k to go before you can stop blaming me ...

Comment: I blame @Randal'Thor for everything.

Comment: @Clockwork I remember when I assumed that realistically I'd never pass 1k on any SE site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Btw the link on your profile page to "Riddlers Den" is not working.

Comment: I'm proud of my 0.101k

Comment: Over 0.1% of the way to 100k after less than 4 years! You're getting close, @hppp.

Comment: Rep isn't everything!!! Ok, I'm super jealous, rep it EVERYTHING! I WANT SOMEE AAAAHHHHH!!!

Comment: Got there in the end ...