# Favorite questions and answers from first quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The summary has now been posted to the [Blog](https://thesffblog.com/2019/04/highlights-from-2019-1st-quarter/).

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2019 through March 31st 2019.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/01/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the most controversial question of the quarter. Also a sum of all the bounties that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

> It is not too late for us to create the dystopian society as envisioned in 1987's The Running Man.

Comment: "*from April 1st 2019 through March 31st 2019*" - I feel a new question coming on: Is Jack B Nimble a Time Lord?

Comment: In the second quarter, it's great to see our very own @Randal'Thor prominently featured in [a piece in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2019/apr/01/whats-the-next-game-of-thrones-all-the-contenders-for-fantasy-tvs-crown).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Bit late for April Fool's, but you got me.

Answer (score 8):

I liked this question. As a long time viewer of Road Runner ([meep, meep!](https://media1.tenor.com/images/2a96c99e84f1e4faa3fe3b8195ff428d/tenor.gif?itemid=5660267)), it was nice to have an excuse to go back through them and a real surprise that there was such a wide variety of non-Acme products.

[Does any Looney Tunes character ever use any fictional brand-name product that isn't ACME?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204999/does-any-looney-tunes-character-ever-use-any-fictional-brand-name-product-that-i)

---

vavskjuta's question about Lex Luthor's epic cake theft was a nice surprise. I always enjoy questions where my gut response is *"Of course not, don't be bloody stupid"*, only to then find out that the opposite is actually true.

[Is Lex Luthor's 40-cake theft canonical?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202622/is-lex-luthors-40-cake-theft-canonical)

Answer (score 1):

Meta wise I think we should certainly highlight this one by myself that congratulates some high level achievements by some of our top users.

[Let's take a moment to congratulate some exceptional users](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12392/58193)

Answer (score 1):

This was a really fun question to answer, mostly because of all the different interpretations of Space-Elevators. [Which was the first story to feature space elevators?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205707/which-was-the-first-story-to-feature-space-elevators/205710#205710)