# Let's (finally) take a moment to congratulate some exceptional users

Tags: discussion, users

A couple of our users "recently" hit some very impressive milestones and I think a post is in order to highlight their amazing achievements.

After taking his sweet sweet time our resident moderator has [*finally*](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12392/58193) hit 100k reputation!

[image]

Hot on his heels was FuzzyBoots who also hit 100k reputation only a few days afterwards!

[image]

---

I, for one, want to take a moment to congratulate these two very impressive users of our site and the amazing contributions they have put forth during their time here.

#### Thank you!

Comment: Congratulations indeed. 100k is a great milestone and one that has traditionally been rewarded by slightly wonky stickers, mugs and other gewgaws from the SE office, delivered months later.

Comment: W00t! Welcome to "I did all the work and all I got was a sticker and a t-shirt, DAMN I'm a sucker!" club! Good job ya'll!

Comment: @Valorum what do they give for 500k? Stock? Please tell me when you find out!

Comment: @TheAsh - I'm assuming it'll be more gubbins from the office. Last time I got a stapler

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - You get a sticker and a t-shirt for 100k?! YAY!

Answer (score 26):

:-D Thank you very much. (You've been waiting a long time for this, haven't you?!)

[image]

Congratulations to FuzzyBoots, not only on hitting 100k just slightly after me, but also on  overtaking me since then and moving into the top 8 users by reputation. May you and 14111 continue riding the wave of story-ID rep ;-)

Comment: LOL fantastic gif!

Answer (score 25):

:) Thank you. I've had a great deal of fun on this site. I honestly hadn't even realized I was approaching such august heights. I'm just having fun.

Comment: Funny, I thought you already had a hundred thousands.

Comment: @Clockwork: Nope. It's been a pretty steady climb, but this was the first time I broached that level.

Comment: I'd hate to think you did this NOT having fun and yet not getting paid :P   Good job!