# Let's take a moment to congratulate some user milestones

Tags: discussion, users

Not too long ago I made a [couple](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12392/58193) of [posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12557/58193) congratulating some of our highest reputation users hitting some of the big milestones. Recently I've noticed a handful of users have reached some lower but still very impressive milestones at a similar time. They are:

#### 10k - DavidW, Shreedhar and Laurel

[image: DavidW's Flair] [image: Shreedhar's Flair] [image: Laurel's Flair]

#### 20k - Mat Cauthon

[image: Mat Cauthon's Flair]

#### 30k - Jenayah

[image: Jenayah's Flair]

As always I want to say thank you to these users for their contributions to our stack and I hope you all do too!

---

<sub>***Disclaimer:** I noticed these milestones had been hit in passing so chances are I may have missed someone out. If I did I'm sorry, let me know and you can be added in!*</sub>

Comment: I'm hurt! I just hit 3,000! :)

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - Keep going. You'll get there soon enough if you keep making quality contributions.

Comment: @Valorum - Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! It was long due, but I only lurk the [tolkiens-legendarium] page nowadays....

Comment: I also just got 10k thanks to getting 3 bounties on my one answer ^_^

Comment: @Laurel it was a good answer though! Added you in and congratulations!

Comment: hey...I don't recall getting a 10k or 20k shout out :D - will keep hustling for 30 I guess! ;) (nbd - I jest in all honesty - congrats indeed to these users) I've definitely slowed down of late - I had a decent pace going for a while)

Comment: @NKCampbell It appears that you hit 20k around the time I hit 10k! If I read the leagues correctly that is...

Comment: Yes, Yanny has been working hard and deserves a mention!